# Rhino Shell invocation: get the line no for a JavaScript runtime exception

Tags: javascript, exception, rhino

I have a JS script that I want to run with rhino.

On the command line I invoke

```
java -cp rhino-1.7R4.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main -f my-script.js
```

Unfortunately the only output I get is

> js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot read property "org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@10d58f09" from undefined

So there is no line information or similar and I have no clue how to identify what is wrong in the script.
(Note: the script is a third party script that I want to modify/fix to be executable with rhino, but where should I begin with this cryptic error message?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run your script in interactive mode (-opt -1)

```
java -classpath js.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main -opt -1 -f my-script.js
```